# How to block specific urls by using robots.txt?

Tags: url, indexing, robots.txt, google-search-console

How can I block specific URLs by using a robots.txt? We do not want Google to crawl our site. How can I define a disallow tag for those URLs in a robots.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude all robots from part of the server you can use this if you want to exclude, for example, these 3 folders:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /junk/
```